# Unable to connect h2o to database via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, h2o

I am trying to connect H2O to a postgres db. I have both the postgres JDBC driver and the H2O jar in the same directory, however I get the following error when I try to start H2O with the driver.

```
java -cp postgresql-42.2.5.jar:h2o.jar water.H2OApp
Error: Could not find or load main class water.H2OApp
```

I've done a clean install of H2O but I still get the following error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using windows command prompt switch the : with a ; and put in double quotes.  I put in the full path also.

```
java -cp "postgresql-42.2.5.jar;h2o.jar" water.H2OApp
```